# When is it useful to use a PHP function that ends with return;

Tags: php, function

What are the best usages of functions that end with "return;" and what are the advantages of writing a function that ends this way?

Example:

```
function MyFunction() {
 // (do something)
 return;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: There is an implicit `return` when code execution hits that last `}` in the function; there's no advantage to including the `return` statement without a return value.

Comment: @Kryten - One benefit of the explicit `return` is that it tells the violent psychopath who knows where you live and who will be maintaining that code in six months time that you deliberately wanted to return a null, and hadn't simply forgotten to return a value

Comment: Good point @MarkBaker. But in that case, an explicit `return null;` would be even better :-)

Comment: @Kryten - and it should also be made clear in your phpdoc block as well.... but I know that violent psychopath and wouldn't want to leave anything to chance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't, I would always use `return null;` so that it is an explicit declaration of what is returned (even if it is `null`).  I'm sure this is also in one of the PSR specs as well, but I don't know them well.  To confirm that `return; === return null;`:

```
function test() {
    return;
}

var_dump(test());
// NULL
```

As to when you would want to `return null;`..any function that returns something, should *always* return something.  So maybe if you have a function that gathers and returns a value from a DB, and an error occurs:

```
public function retrieveData()
{
    $data = DB::retrieve();

    if(!$data) {
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

However, a lot of functions that may have errors just return `true`/`false` on success or failure so you won't necessarily use this often.

My main point to drive home: if you don't want/need to return anything, don't return anything.

Comment: I'm not sure I see any benefit of the `return null` here because it will _never_ be executed; the `throw` will terminate execution of the function first, and then the result of the retrieveData() call isn't accessible anywhere

Comment: Good point @MarkBaker, I just removed my `throw` line. That wasn't (/isn't) really the best example, I was trying to get the point across that there is usually a better method than to use `return null;`..

Answer (score 1):

A `return;` says only "thats the end". Mostly useful in following examples:

```
 function test($string) {
      if(empty($string)) {
           return; // If the variable is empty, then stop to work!
      }

      echo $string;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is that you can write a PHP function that spits out formatted HTML:

```
function printHeader($value)
{
  echo "<h1>$value</h1>";
  return;
}
```

However, since you are not returning anything, the `return` statement is unnecessary and can be left out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a empty `return;`, I can think of one example, if you have code that should be executed under a condition, and more code that should be executed if that condition is not met.

```
function MyFunction() {
 if(a < 1) {
 // (do something)
 return;
 }
 // If a >= 0 it executes the code above and the code below
 // Do something else
}
```